# How to call function in jquery on document.ready

Tags: jquery

I want to show an alert on click of a radio button, but I dont want to do it as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:radio').on('click',function(){
    alert('hi');
  });
});
```

Rather, I want to create a function with my logic and call function on document.ready

Comment: This is the best way to do it though. Waiting until the checkbox exists, then adding the listener. Otherwise you would need to add the `onclick` to the html. The above code is fine though

Comment: what problem are you facing with your approach?

Comment: I am not sure if you want to call a function inside of the doc ready function or pass the function that you defined to doc ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a regular function object into `ready`:

```
function myfunc(){
  $('input:radio').on('click',function(){
    alert('hi');
  });
}

$(document).ready(myfunc);
```